# Writing specific values from list

Tags: python-2.7, loops

I come with a short question. I've wrote this part of code, where from an array of my data, values are saved when the condition below is fulfilled. Right now I'd like to narrow a little bit this condition and write a function, which will save only data above some value.
For e.g. 
`res >= 100.0`.

```
res = [j for i, j, k in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]) if i < j and j > k]
with open("S:\Doc\Python\Data\Codes\BxHPF.txt", 'w') as Peak1:
    Peak1.write(str(res))
    Peak1.close()
```

Comment: `res` is a list, what does `res >= 100.0` mean?

Comment: Do you mean `j >= 100.0`? Add that to the conditions in the list comprehension.

Comment: You don't need to call `Peak1.close()`, that's done automatically by `with`.

Comment: You can also combine all the conditions into `j > max(i, k, 100.0)`

Comment: @Barmar Well you are probably right, it supposed to be `j` instead of `res` so should I write `if j>=100.0` and after that this `Peak1.write(str(res))` ? I'd be grateful if you can post the code, cause I'm a little bit confused, plus I will be able to mark your answer as a correct one :)

Comment: No, it should be in the list comprehension `if i < j and j > k and j >= 100.0`

Comment: If this isn't obvious, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want.

Comment: This function answers my question. `if i < j and j > k and j >= 100.0` Please post it so I can mark as a correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the additional condition to the list comprehension.

```
res = [j for i, j, k in zip(lst, lst[1:], lst[2:]) if i < j and j > k and j >= 100.0]
```

Comment: I wonder if you respond, but I'll try. I would like to extend this part of code you have written for me. So I have this code where it takes all the values of the condition `if i < j and j > k and j >= 100.0`. Well I take this data from my plot and with x axis I have time, saved in `BxTime` list, how to zip your code and this `BxTime` list, so after checking my data, program will save values which fullfill the condition above, but also time on the scale (the one from `BxTime` list)?